# C# Google Analytics UnsampledReports.Insert returns 'Insufficient Permission [403]'

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

My C# program succeeds in calling the Analytics Core API and the Management API of the Google Premium account I have (by proxy settings).

Examples of successful calls by my 'AnalyticsService service' are:

```
service.Management.Accounts.List();
service.Management.Webproperties.List(account.Id);
service.Management.Profiles.List(account.Id, webproperty.Id);
service.Data.Ga.Get("ga:" + profile_id, end_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), end_date.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "ga:uniqueEvents,ga:eventValue");
service.Management.UnsampledReports.List(results.ProfileInfo.AccountId, results.ProfileInfo.WebPropertyId, results.ProfileInfo.ProfileId).Execute();
service.Management.UnsampledReports.Get(results.ProfileInfo.AccountId, results.ProfileInfo.WebPropertyId, results.ProfileInfo.ProfileId, file_entry.Id).Execute();
```

I have tried to understand the authentication scope of GET/POST in service.Management.UnsampledReports.Insert by reading the documentation
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUnsampledReports
but when I try to insert an unsampled report in my C# program I get the error:

```
The service analytics has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Insufficient Permission [403]
Errors [
    Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]
```

The code is:

```
UnsampledReport report = new UnsampledReport();
report.Title = "Test the API";
report.StartDate = "2014-10-21";
report.EndDate = "2014-10-22";
report.Metrics = "ga:uniqueEvents,ga:eventValue";
report.Dimensions = "ga:Dimension1, ga:Dimension2, ga:Dimension3, ga:eventAction";
report.Filters = "ga:Dimension1=~10.0.A.;ga:eventAction=~.*100$";
try
{
  service.Management.UnsampledReports.Insert(report, results.ProfileInfo.AccountId, results.ProfileInfo.WebPropertyId, results.ProfileInfo.ProfileId).Execute();
}
catch (Exception google_exception)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} UnsampledReports.Insert caught", google_exception);
}
```

where 'results' is the result of successful calls to 
`DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest data_request = service.Data.Ga.Get(...`
and `GaData results = data_request.Execute();`

I am able to create un-sampled reports by the Web-interface provided by Google Premium, it is possible to list these reports and get them in C# but I am unable to insert un-sampled reports from C#. Two metrics and four dimensions with filters should be supported according to the documentation. I noticed that flat tables in the Web-interface only support two dimensions but I think four should be ok.

I am using the latest Nuget versions of:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Analytics.v3;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data;
```

I am using this authentication scope:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path_secret + @"\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics, 
            AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit,
            AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly },
    "Test user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("Analytics.Auth.Store")).Result;
}
```

1. Is there any way of turning on debug printouts of the URI generated by the API code?
2. Is Wireshark the best way to debug this type of trouble?
3. I have not been able to find the complete source code by the .zip files available, where should I look?
4. Anyone with tips and tricks regarding how to implement the call **service.Management.UnsampledReports.Insert** ?

Thank you!

Comment: The user that you are logging into your application with. What level access do they have?  I suspect the problem is with access to inserts I am checking something with the Devs I will get back to you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My bad! Re-reading the documentation I realized my first scope in the code was AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly and I accepted an Oauth2 token supporting this scope. Somewhat unexpectedly, adding two new scopes: Analytics and AnalyticsEdit in the code does not trigger a request for a new OAuth2 token with the right scope authorization.

Comment: if you change "Test user" to something else it will force them to reauth as you are using filedatastore the authentication is stored on your pc under that name. changing the name will cause it to reauth because it cant find it.  you only need the first one it will give you everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer scope may change in the code and the only solution I found so far to trigger a request of a new Oauth2 token is to patch the string 'user' in the credential request GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync. This is an ugly work-around and I hope to find the correct call to force a request of a new Oauth2 token when the scope is changed in the code. The alternative in updating deployed clients would be to invent some type of version management of scope in the 'user' field. This would be error prone and difficult to maintain.